# Is this possible to add a custom onChange function to the default FormControl in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Is this possible to add a custom onChange function to the default FormControl?  Currently I've seen examples on registering onchange functions on a custom input but non on the default FormControl.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Default FormControl'? Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Do you mean hooking into when the value of the form control changes? This question isn't entirely clear and it would be helpful if you could post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: When calling `new FormControl('');`  Can I later call a registerOnChange on that object?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to bind to the change events for FormControls. For `input` boxes you need to bind to the `input` event and for `dropdown` boxes you need to bind to the `change` event.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input  formControlName="inputControl"
          (input)="inputChange()"
          placeholder="Enter a Value"/>
    <select formControlName="dropdownControl"
            (change)="dropdownChange()">
        <option>Beetle</option>
        <option>Lady Bug</option>
        <option>Grasshopper</option>
        <option>Firefly</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is a [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/XWIPgTT0bOVsAn5cGwfW?show=preview) demonstrating how the events work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add that you can register a change event on any `FormControl`, using [`FormControl.registerOnChange`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#registeronchange):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss']
})
export class Foo implements OnInit {
    public Bar = new FormControl('');

    constructor () {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.Bar.registerOnChange(()=>{console.log(this.Bar.value);});
    }
}
```

That'll work for anything bound to that `FormControl` that fires `onChange` events.